# Bluetooth 5 adapters

Tags: usb, bluetooth, bluetooth-5, bluetooth-adapter

I was wanting to play with with Bluetooth 5 with some current code.  Does anyone know where I could get a bluetooth 5 (low energy HCI) adapter?  Preferably USB.

Comment: Interesting, I was looking for the same thing.   Simply speaking, USB Bluetooth 5 adapters supporting the extended range or higher bitrate don't seem to be available here in summer 2017, almost a year after the specs released.

Comment: I am also looking for a personal daily use Bluetooth 5 USB 3.0 adapter.
It's 2020 and still not many are out there